# Ubuntu's MIR, and Gnome-Shell's on Wayland = Ubuntu problems since 13.10?

Tags: gnome, wayland, mir

If Ubuntu is going to use MIR with Ubuntu 13.10, and Gnome is going to use Wayland with Gnome Shell 3.10, will there be any problems to have gnome-shell up to date in Ubuntu 13.10?

Because some dependencies are going to be installed when I will install Gnome Shell right? Or is that what the [Ubuntu GNOME](http://ubuntugnome.com/) flavor was made for? To avoid that problem?

But what about people who would like to have Unity and Gnome Shell Desktop Environments?

Answer (score 5):

In GNOME 3.10 Xorg will still be the default display server as stated in https://live.gnome.org/Wayland, however in the future version of GNOME (3.12), Xorg is going to be fully replaced with Wayland, yet maintaining some degree of Xorg compatibility.

Comment: so then, if id like to have gnome-shell (newest one), i gotta go to another distro? ;d

Comment: no, not another distro entirely, but to keep things clean, probably a derivative or "remix" of Ubuntu that cuts out the Mir + Unity and replaces it with Wayland + Gnome.

Comment: As of GNOME 3.18, Wayland is *still* not default.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that GNOME will still support X in 3.12. According to https://live.gnome.org/Wayland#Proposed_roadmap, most parts of GNOME will still work under X.

If you do not need Unity and Mir/X then [Ubuntu GNOME flavor](http://ubuntugnome.com/) will probably be using Wayland when Gnome switches compatibility. Ubuntu GNOME is a Ubuntu flavor that uses Gnome shell as the default Desktop Environment. It still has mostly all features of Ubuntu but includes Gnome Shell instead of Unity.